# Spring not loading AWS-SNS credentials from properties file

Tags: java, spring, amazon-sns

I am building an application that reads data from SQL Server databases and then will send SMS text messages based on certain data.

The application is in Java, with Spring and Maven.

The problem I am encountering is my application.properties file is not being loaded in correctly. I get an "IllegalArguementException: Access Key cannot be null" when amazonSNS is created

I have two properties files, one for dev one for prod

I have tried using @PropertySource in my AppConfig class to specify which properties file to load in, I still get null for aws access value. However i dont want to use @PropertySource because I have two profiles dev and prod

My application-dev.properties AWS credentials are as such

```
aws.sns.type=Transactional
aws.access=123456etc
aws.secret=123456etc
```

AppConfig file

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.application")
@EnableIntegration
@EnableScheduling
public class AppConfig implements EnvironmentAware {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppConfig.class);

    private Environment environment;
    @Value("${aws.access}")
    private String awsAccessKey;
    @Value("${aws.secret}")
    private String awsSecretKey;

    @Bean
    public AmazonSNS amazonSNS() {
        BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
        AmazonSNS snsClient = AmazonSNSClient.builder().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basicAWSCredentials)).build();
        logger.info("Creating snsClient");
        return snsClient;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

so to fix this I learned that @Value was not working for some reason. Intellij was telling me that it knew what that value was but when it was loaded it was null

so instead of using @Value to get the aws.access and aws.secret I used this.environment.getProperty("aws.access")

like this

`BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(this.environment.getProperty("aws.access"), this.environment.getProperty("aws.secret"));`